# POSIX interprocess synchronization

Tags: linux, synchronization, posix, ipc

I'm creating a platform-independent data visualizer and want it to work like this:

1. A caller creates a new process of the visualizer (CreateProcess on Windows and
   fork-and-exec on Linux)
2. The caller creates some synchronizing object and blocks on it
3. The visualizer find the object and signal it

I know I can achieve step 2 and 3 with named events on Windows, but how should I do it on Linux?

Thanks.

Comment: Probably a named semaphore.

Comment: @Duck Yeah it's exactly what I want! Add an answer to the question so I can accept it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this with a [named semaphore](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/sem_overview.7.html) although it may have to go more like (1) create semaphore, (2) fork/exec; (3) parent waits on semaphore; (4) visualizer posts.  If there is only a parent/child relationship here you could use an unnamed semaphore but you have to set up shared memory first.  Named are a little more flexible.

Comment: I have implemented something same like this, and it works well... However on windows the event object gets deleted if all the processes referring the event are deleted, however, on linux, the semaphore object remains persistent, is some cases if my process crashes..
How to avoid this behavior.